# How to best dispose of question that adds information to another question?

Tags: discussion, images

[Can anyone read this cut off text in margin?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/13752/2586) adds an image from the adjacent page that picks up the portion that ran into the curve of the book binding in the first image and was not totally clear.

Should we keep this question or delete it?

If we delete it, how do we preserve the information added with the second image and comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On that question there is a [comment by @bgwiehle](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13752/can-anyone-read-this-cut-off-text-in-margin#comment20259_13752) that says:

> The second image above confirmed the most likely reading of the word
>   already suggested by an earlier answer; so this question might be
>   considered redundant.

Consequently, I think that this question should probably be made a duplicate of the question with the answer mentioned above.  If, you are not able to do that yourself, then feel free to provide a link to that Q&A, and then the community or one of its moderators will be able to vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Upvoted because I agree that making the question a duplicate is probably the cleanest way to go.

Comment: Rather than delete, I've voted to close as a dup of https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/what-are-names-and-dates-in-this-status-animarum-for-mali-cirnik-13 I need more votes to close though.